# Trouble installing rmagick gem in Ubuntu (already installed ImageMagick successfully)

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick

Trust me when I tell you I've read each and every single thing on Stack related to this question (I know a few others have asked this).

OS: Ubuntu 10.04
Ruby: 1.8.7

I installed the latest build of ImageMagick by following their guidelines. I had a couple of problems, but was able to solve them and ultimately managed to get the 'test' command to spit out the correct result (i.e. convert logo: filename.png -- which successfully changed the png file I gave it into a logo of ImageMagick, thus affirming that ImageMagick is installed correctly).

Now when I do sudo gem install rmagick I get the following result:

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from extconf.rb:1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out

Would be eternally grateful for some assistance on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, finally.

I added this to my .bashrc file (to pick-up MagickCore.pc):

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
```

I then created two symlinks:

```
ln -s /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/wand /usr/local/include/wand ln -s
/usr/local/include/ImageMagick/magick /usr/local/include/magick
```

After this I was able to install rmagick by simply typing gem install rmagick.

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates you need `mkmf.rb` which is part of the `ruby1.8-dev` package.

Try `sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`. Hopefully it should work after that.

Comment: Updated my answer to include another required package.